# Creating a poll in Sharepoint Online (lists or other approach)

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

There seem to be many web parts available for on-premise versions of SharePoint but I've not been able to find an easy way of doing them on SharePoint Online.

My idea was to create a list that had a column for responses (radio buttons) and then create an unstyled new item form for that list that could be added to a page in a content editor web part to create the poll.

My issue is that I can't seem to create a version of the list input form that doesn't have the ribbon etc on it.

Does anyone know how to do this or have another approach of adding a poll to a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: After using Google, SharePoint has its own solution, that can be found here: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=80

There are enough scripts available on the net where you can create polls by yourself by using generators. If you're having a bit of knowledge, you should be able to create one by yourself.

You should check out www.hotscripts.com for sure, make sure you'll test 3 - 5 different scripts, this will force you to learn more about the code(-behind) and your personal preferables.

Comment: Thanks but I really need something that's internal to sharepoint.  I don't want to be supporting 3rd party or bespoke code for this.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=80 (Just Googled it)

Comment: That's spot on, if a bit harder to find on the online version.  Make a separate answer so I can accept it :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a dataview webpart. Choose the one column, and insert as new form.